# Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0.a)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My project required rvm 2.5.1. I just installed it and changed using rvm use 2.5.1.

And then I run

```
bundle install
```

I got an error with:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0.a) among 20 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/sonu/.rvm/gems/ruby- 
2.5.1:/home/sonu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global', execute `gem env` for more information
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in `to_spec'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

Please help me out.

When I run **gem env** cammand I got this result

```
gem env
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.6
- RUBY VERSION: 2.5.1 (2018-03-29 patchlevel 57) [x86_64-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/sonu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1
- USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/sonu/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/sonu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/sonu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/sonu/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-linux
- GEM PATHS:
   - /home/sonu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1
   - /home/sonu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
   - :sources => ["https://rubygems.org/", "http://rubygems.org"]
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - https://rubygems.org/
   - http://rubygems.org
```

Comment: Did you try doing a `gem install bundler` ?

Comment: Yes I tried all this cammand also :-
    gem install bundler,  
    sudo gem install bundler, 
    gem install rubygems-bundler

but not getting success...

Comment: Adding the output for `gem env` should be helpful.

Comment: Add it to the question(you can do that by clicking "edit" under the question), it is not readable in this state.

Comment: When you run `bundle env` do you get any output? If so what is it?